# What is the correct way to stop a thread waiting for network activity?

Tags: java, multithreading, networking, interrupt-handling

This question has no doubt been asked in various forms in the past, but not so much for a specific scenario.

What is the most correct way to stop a Thread that is blocking while waiting to receive a network message over UDP.

For example, say I have the following Thread:

```
public class ClientDiscoveryEngine extends Thread {

    private final int PORT;

    public ClientDiscoveryEngine(final int portNumber) {
        PORT = portNumber;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            socket = new DatagramSocket(RECEIVE_PORT);

            while (true) {
                final byte[] data = new byte[256];
                final DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(data, data.length);

                socket.receive(packet);
            }
        } catch (SocketException e) {
            // do stuff 1
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // do stuff 2
        }
    }
}
```

Now, would the more correct way be using the `interrupt()` method? For example adding the following method:

```
@Override
public void interrupt() {
    super.interrupt();
    // flip some state?
}
```

My only concern is, is `socket.receive()` not a non-interruptable blocking method? The one way that I have thought of would be to implement the interrupt method as above, in that method call `socket.close()` and then cater for it in the `run` method in the catch for the `SocketException`. Or maybe instead of `while(true)` use some state that gets flipped in the interrupt method. Is this the best way? Or is there a more elegant way?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The receive method doesn't seem to be interruptible. You could close the socket: the javadoc says:

> Any thread currently blocked in `receive(java.net.DatagramPacket)` upon
>   this socket will throw a SocketException

You could also use `setSoTimeout` to make the receive method block only for a small amount of time. After the method has returned, your thread can check if it has been interrupted, and retry to receive again for this small amount of time.

Answer (score 3):

Read this answer [Interrupting a thread that waits on a blocking action?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1820118/interrupting-a-thread-that-waits-on-a-blocking-action/1820432#1820432)

Answer (score 2):

To stop a thread, you should not user neither interrupt nor stop in java. The best way, as you suggested by the end of your question, is to have the loop inside the main method controlled by a flag that you can rise as needed.

Here is an old link about this :
http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/misc/threadPrimitiveDeprecation.html

Other ways of stopping a thread are deprecated and don't provide as much control as this one. Also, this may have changed a bit with executor services, I didn't have time to learn much about it yet.

Also, if you want to avoid your thread to be blocked in some IO state, waiting for a socket, you should give your socket a connection and reading time out (method `setSoTimeout`).

Regards,
 Stéphane

Comment: Err, no. interrupt is there to stop a thread. It's actually the only way to do it if the thread might be blocked in a blocking call which reacts to interrupts (like Thread.sleep, Object.wait, reading from an interruptible channel, etc.). Read http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/interrupt.html.

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the easier ones.  If it's blocked on a UDP socket, send the socket a UDP message that instructs the receiving thread to 'stop'.

Rgds,
Martin